# Find if every value is the same

Tags: sql-server-2008

my problem:

I have table Table1:

```
ClientID Open
1         1
2         1
3         0
```

And table2:

```
  ClientID  Date    Rate     
    1          01    1
    1          02    2
    1          03    2 
    2          01    1
    2          02    1
    2          03    1
    3          01    1
    3          02    2
    3          03    2
```

And i want to find open clients (open =1) where the value "Rate" hasnt changed for them. That means i want to find client number 2 ( Open client and the Rate is still the same) but not client number 1 (hes is also open, but his Rate is different (1,2,2)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open is a reserved word It may have to be in []'s  I can't remember MSFTs rules on this

```
SELECT t1.clientID
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.clientID=T2.ClientID
WHERE t1.[open] = 1
GROUP BY t1.clientID
HAVING count(Distinct t2.rate) = 1
```

This is a an inner join on client ID to get a set of data consisting of rate and open status for each client.  The results are limited to only open clients who have a count of distinct rates of 1.

If the count is not 1 that means the there were different rates for the client which isn't what you wanted.  The key here is the `count(Distinct field)` within the having clause.  Distinct forces there to be unique values only of rate for each client; and if the client has a distinct count > 1 then they must have had a rate change.